# How can I create a model package group and add an existing a model package to this group using a lambda function for the model package versioning

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-version.html

I referred this AWS Doc for model package group creation and I was able to create a group. But here versioning of model packages are described only while creating of the respective model package. But I want to add an already existing model package to the group which I created. Is somebody can help. I tried searching for boto3 API, but I got none. I searched with updating the modelpackage with modelpackagegroupname as parameter using update_model_package API. But it doesnt support that.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new model package in the model package group is the best way to achieve this.